# Spring Boot Update at 2 Classes at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, dto

I start a project with spring boot, I use a database with 6 tables.
It is a CRUD application .

So , I have my entities/dto/service/controller/repository packages for 5 tables. (6  tables in SQL)

Now, I would like to update a row on the column of table x(SQL) of entity x to another entity y at a specific row.

In my opinion, it should be done at the service layer at create X, but how?

Should I create a xyDTO with data from 2 entities? I am afraid of doing it , the table y it doesn't update automatically.But when create the xyDTO. I don't want this.

How I can update the data of specific DTO x to another DTO y (6th table of SQL), at the same time

I cannot find  similar example online.  Could anyone help me?

My code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "repo")
public class Repo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name="stock")
    private Long stock;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "voucher")
public class Voucher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private BigDecimal quantity;
 
    @Column(name = "type")
    private boolean type;
}

@Service
public class VoucherService{
    @Override
    public Voucher dtoToEntity(VoucherDTO dto) {
        Voucher voucher = new Voucher();
        voucher.setId(dto.getId());     
        voucher.setDescription(dto.getDescription());
 
        List<VoucherProduct> voucherList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (VoucherProductDTOMini inv : dto.getVoucherproducts()) {
            VoucherProduct voucherL = voucherProductService.DTOtoEntity(inv);        
            voucherList.add(voucherL);
        }
    
        voucher.setVoucherproducts(voucherList);
        return voucher;
    }
    
    @Override
    public VoucherDTO createVoucher(VoucherDTO voucherDTO) {
        Voucher voucher=new Voucher();
        voucher=voucherRepository.save(voucher);

        VoucherDTO voucherDTOnew=new VoucherDTO(voucher);
        return voucherDTOnew;
    }
}
```

I should
check the type of my voucher (true), and I should add on my repo entity at
stock.

In which way can I update the two entities at the same time?

When I add a true voucher, I should add on my `repo.stock` the data of `voucher.quantity`.

Comment: Please clarify your question better, as it is hard to understand what you are trying to do.
If you are trying to update the foreign key column then please mention it directly. Also it would be better to provide your code for your entities so we would understand the relations in your DB.

Comment: Basically the flow should be like this: **Get the entity you need to update** *(let the Hibernate handle all the queries and lazy-loading)* -> **Change the property you want to** -> **Save**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your tips. I add some of my code on my post, it may help.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to highlight a few things in your code:

1. I cannot find the reason to use `@Override` annotation on those methods in your Service.
2. In `createVoucher` method you create completely empty entity, this is not a good thing to do.

**DTO** stands for Data Transfer Object, and usually in Spring applications it is used to transfer data *to* or *from* the service. For example: **Controllers**. When user makes a *Http Request* to receive all *Vouchers* for example, you would like to return *VoucherDto* with only those fields that you want users to see.

You can have different **DTO** objects for *Getting* entity values and *Updating* them. Because sometimes you want to allow users to update only certain properties.

---

To answer your question on how to update two entities in a single call. As I understood your question, you want to update different properties in two different entities via a single request. This is possible, though there are different approaches to this.

1. Create two different **DTO**s, one for each entity. Create two different *Http Requests* each would take one DTO and call a method in a service to update each *Entity*. *ex.*: **VoucherController.updateVoucher** *->* **VoucherService.updateVoucher** and **RepoController.updateRepo** *->* **RepoService.updateRepo**. I personally prefer this as a solution because your entities *Voucher* and *Repo* don't have any relation.
2. Create a single **DTO** object, containing all fields required to be updated, then in the service method find your **Voucher**, and **Repo** and update their fields, then *save both entities*. This would be a messy approach when you have many entities.

There would be another different approach if you would have a relation between your *Repo* and *Voucher* entities, for example a *OneToMany*.

---

Let me know whether this answers your question. There is nothing wrong to have many *DTO* objects and *Services*, etc.

If you would like to easily generate all the **DTO** objects, have a look at this: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Comment: @CareyLynda glad to hear that, If this did answer your question, please mark it as an answer